# splitting the list in two parts in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a array which is inside the for loop which is to be first converted to an list and then split into 2 halves the first part of the list is being stored in s1 list and second part is being stored in w1,this is to be done recursively till the loop ends and in the end of the method i will be returning both s1 and w1 this is the code i have done so far-:

```
   public Pair daubTrans( double s[] ) throws Exception
    {
     final int N = s.length;
      int n;
    //double t1[] = new double[100000];
     //List<Double> t1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    // double s1[] = new double[100000];
    List<double[]> w1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
  List<double[]> s1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
 List<double[]> lList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
  //List<double[]> t1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();

  for (n = N; n >= 4; n >>= 1) {
      double[] t1=  transform( s, n );
      int length = t1.length;
     // System.out.println(n);
     // LinkedList<double> t1 =new LinkedList<double>( Arrays.asList(t1));

     /* for(double[] d: t1)
      {
          t1.add(d);
      }*/

      lList = Arrays.asList(t1);
      length=lList.size();
      //System.out.print(lList.size());

     // System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)
/*   s1= t1.subList(0, 1);
     w1= t1.subList(0, 1); */
   /*    if(n==N)
     {
     s1= lList.subList(0, length/2-1);
     w1= lList.subList(length/2-1, length);
     }
     else
     {
     s1=lList.subList(( length/2), length);
      w1=lList.subList(( length/2), length);
     } */

//    System.arraycopy(t1,0, s1, n==N?0:t1.size()/2-1, t1.size()/2-1);
 // System.arraycopy(t1,(length/2), w1, n==N?0:t1.size()/2-1, t1.size()/2-1);
 // System.out.println(w1.length);

  }
  return new Pair(s1, w1);

 }
```

where pair class is defined so as to return the 2 list and transform returns an array of type double which is being stored in t1 array.
now i am getting problem in converting t1 array to list type and also on how to split the list formed by elements of t1 into 2 parts. THE CODE FOR TRANSFORM IS -:

```
      protected  double[] transform( double a[], int n )
    {
       if (n >= 4) {
        int i, j;
       int half = n >> 1;

    double tmp[] = new double[n];

    i = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n-3; j = j + 2) {
          tmp[i]      = a[j]*h0 + a[j+1]*h1 + a[j+2]*h2 + a[j+3]*h3;
          tmp[i+half] = a[j]*g0 + a[j+1]*g1 + a[j+2]*g2 + a[j+3]*g3;
       i++;
         }
    // System.out.println(i);

     tmp[i]      = a[n-2]*h0 + a[n-1]*h1 + a[0]*h2 + a[1]*h3;
     tmp[i+half] = a[n-2]*g0 + a[n-1]*g1 + a[0]*g2 + a[1]*g3;


     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = tmp[i];

     }



  }


return a;
   } // transform
```

this is the whole code-:

```
  import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.List;
    import java.util.*;
     import java.lang.Math.*;

  class daub {
   protected final double sqrt_3 = Math.sqrt( 3 );
   protected final double denom = 4 * Math.sqrt( 2 );
    //
    // forward transform scaling (smoothing) coefficients
    //
    protected final double h0 = (1 + sqrt_3)/denom;
      protected final double h1 = (3 + sqrt_3)/denom; 
           protected final double h2 = (3 - sqrt_3)/denom; 
              protected final double h3 = (1 - sqrt_3)/denom;
         //
    // forward transform wavelet coefficients
        //
            protected final double g0 =  h3;
           protected final double g1 = -h2;
               protected final double g2 =  h1;
                protected final double g3 = -h0;

          //
           // Inverse transform coefficients for smoothed values
           //
           protected final double Ih0 = h2;
             protected final double Ih1 = g2;  // h1
           protected final double Ih2 = h0;
            protected final double Ih3 = g0;  // h3
           //
          // Inverse transform for wavelet values
               //
            protected final double Ig0 = h3;
         protected final double Ig1 = g3;  // -h0
           protected final double Ig2 = h1;
           protected final double Ig3 = g1;  // -h2
             List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
       /**
        <p>
           Forward wavelet transform.

       protected  double[] transform( double a[], int n )
     {
  if (n >= 4) {
     int i, j;
     int half = n >> 1;

 double tmp[] = new double[n];

 i = 0;
     for (j = 0; j < n-3; j = j + 2) {
        tmp[i]      = a[j]*h0 + a[j+1]*h1 + a[j+2]*h2 + a[j+3]*h3;
        tmp[i+half] = a[j]*g0 + a[j+1]*g1 + a[j+2]*g2 + a[j+3]*g3;
    i++;
     }
    // System.out.println(i);

     tmp[i]      = a[n-2]*h0 + a[n-1]*h1 + a[0]*h2 + a[1]*h3;
     tmp[i+half] = a[n-2]*g0 + a[n-1]*g1 + a[0]*g2 + a[1]*g3;


     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = tmp[i];

     }



  }


return a;
```

} // transform

```
         protected void invTransform( double a[], int n )
     {
  if (n >= 4) {
int i, j;
int half = n >> 1;
int halfPls1 = half + 1;

double tmp[] = new double[n];

//      last smooth val  last coef.  first smooth  first coef
tmp[0] = a[half-1]*Ih0 + a[n-1]*Ih1 + a[0]*Ih2 + a[half]*Ih3;
tmp[1] = a[half-1]*Ig0 + a[n-1]*Ig1 + a[0]*Ig2 + a[half]*Ig3;
j = 2;
for (i = 0; i < half-1; i++) {
  //     smooth val     coef. val       smooth val    coef. val
  tmp[j++] = a[i]*Ih0 + a[i+half]*Ih1 + a[i+1]*Ih2 + a[i+halfPls1]*Ih3;
  tmp[j++] = a[i]*Ig0 + a[i+half]*Ig1 + a[i+1]*Ig2 + a[i+halfPls1]*Ig3;
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  a[i] = tmp[i];
}
  }
      }


         /**
           Forward Daubechies D4 transform
          */
          public Pair daubTrans( double s[] ) throws Exception
       {
  final int N = s.length;
  int n;
  //double t1[] = new double[100000];
  //List<Double> t1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
 // double s1[] = new double[100000];
  List<double[]> w1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
  List<double[]> s1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
 List<double[]> lList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
  //List<double[]> t1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();

  for (n = N; n >= 4; n >>= 1) {
      double[] t1=  transform( s, n );
      int length = t1.length;
     // System.out.println(n);
     // LinkedList<double> t1 =new LinkedList<double>( Arrays.asList(t1));

     /* for(double[] d: t1)
      {
          t1.add(d);
      }*/

      lList = Arrays.asList(t1);
      length=lList.size();
      //System.out.print(lList.size());

     // System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)
/*   s1= t1.subList(0, 1);
     w1= t1.subList(0, 1); */
 if(n==N)
     {
     s1= lList.subList(0, length/2-1);
     w1= lList.subList(length/2-1, length);
     }
     else
     {
     s1=lList.subList(( length/2), length);
      w1=lList.subList(( length/2), length);
     } 

//    System.arraycopy(t1,0, s1, n==N?0:t1.size()/2-1, t1.size()/2-1);
 // System.arraycopy(t1,(length/2), w1, n==N?0:t1.size()/2-1, t1.size()/2-1);
 // System.out.println(w1.length);

  }
  return new Pair(s1, w1);
```

}

```
        /**
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use an IDE with *auto-formatting*.

Comment: You should probably provide more details on "now i am getting problem in  ..."

Comment: @guest i am getting error in conversion from array type to list type and i am not able to split the lList in to 2 parts inside the the for loop

Comment: @christian i am using eclipse but even dat is not giving me a correct solution

Comment: @user3262269 It won't give you the solution but it will make your code more clear and readable, so it will be easier to visualize what is happening. It's just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add the code of `transform(s,n)` to this question.
2. Why this? `for (n = N; n >= 4; n >>= 1) {}` It seems to be easier: `for (int n = N; n >= 4; n--) {}`
3. This is crazy: `List<double[]>` If you'd like to use a list of doubles then use this: `List<double>`
4. What is the result that you would like to see?

Comment: i have used n>>-1 since i have to pass half of the array each time to transform(s,n) fxn;and in the end i would like to have 2 list s1 and w1 where s1 is formed from first half of the list lList returned in each iteration with apppending of the content in s1 and not rewritting whereas w1 is the list made from second half of the list lList

Comment: Hm, I think you select a little bit complex selection method... For the further code analyse, could you clear the code above, please?